# Get Unicode point of NSString and put that into another NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unicode, nsstring

What's the easiest way to get the Unicode value from an `NSString`? For example,

```
NSString *str = "A";
NSString *hex;
```

Now, I want to set the value of `hex` to the Unicode value of `str` (i.e. 0041)... How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `unichar` type is defined to be a 16-bit unicode value (eg, as indirectly documented in the [description of the %C specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)), and you can get a `unichar` from a given position in an `NSString` using [`characterAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex%3a), or use [`getCharacters:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getCharacters%3arange%3a) if you want to fill a C array of unichars from the `NSString` more quickly than by querying them one by one.

`NSUTF32StringEncoding` is also a valid string encoding, as are a couple of endian-specific variants, in case you want to be absolutely future proof. You'd get a C array of those using the much more longwinded [`getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getBytes%3amaxLength%3ausedLength%3aencoding%3aoptions%3arange%3aremainingRange%3a).

EDIT: so, e.g.

```
NSString *str = @"A";

NSLog(@"16-bit unicode values are:");
for(int index = 0; index < [str length]; index++)
    NSLog(@"%04x", [str characterAtIndex:index]);
```

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the prompt response, however, I'm kind of a new to Obj-C. Could you provide a code snippet/example usage?

Comment: Because I when I do `code`NSString *hexValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", @"<"];`code`, I get 棰

Comment: That's because `@"<"` is a string and hence an object, but `%C` expects a literal. You've sadly fallen into the fault line between the object-oriented world of Objective-C and the literal value old world of C. You'd use `%@` to specify an object, or `'<'` to place a character as a literal — though in both cases you'd need to be careful in general because unicode characters in source code don't necessarily survive compilation (despite `NSString` being fully unicode aware; it's a toolchain issue not a runtime issue).

Comment: Ok, thanks Tommy! Checked yours as correct.

Edit: I would upvote also, but I need 15 rep apparently... so hopefully users see the giant check mark!

Comment: Only for later reference: semantically, `unichar` is UTF-16 character, not an Unicode code point. They roughly matches, but not exactly equals.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
NSData * u = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSString *hex = [u description];
```

You may replace NSUnicodeStringEncoding by NSUTF8StringEncoding, NSUTF16StringEncoding (the same as NSUnicodeStringEncoding) or NSUTF32StringEncoding, or many other values.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/String_Encodings)
 for more

Comment: Cool alternative; also worth noting that an `NSData` contains a single atomic block of memory holding the relevant data so you can grab its `bytes` property and cast that appropriately to walk through as a C array if you like. Just be careful to pay attention to `length`. So this is a much cleaner way of getting an array of the 32 bit UTF codes than allocating your own buffer and using `getBytes:maxLength:...` as per my answer.